# While using Mysql cast function getting the Check Mysql version or the right syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

```
SELECT EM.rec_id AS rec_id,EM.employee_code, EM.employee_name, EM.designation,   EM.weekly_off_day, EM.gender, EM.payment_type, SM.shift_name, PM.plant_name, EM.status AS status,EM.settlement_no,
    SCM.section_name
    FROM employee_master AS EM 
    INNER JOIN shift_master AS SM ON EM.shift_rec_id = SM.rec_id 
    INNER JOIN section_master AS SCM ON EM.section_rec_id = SCM.rec_id 
    INNER JOIN plant_master AS PM ON EM.plant_rec_id = PM.rec_id
    ORDER BY CAST(EM.employee_code As INT)
```

This is the sql I am using. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EM.rec_id AS rec_id,EM.employee_code, EM.employee_name, EM.designation,   EM.weekly_off_day, EM.gender, EM.payment_type, SM.shift_name, PM.plant_name, EM.status AS status,EM.settlement_no,
    SCM.section_name
    FROM employee_master AS EM 
    INNER JOIN shift_master AS SM ON EM.shift_rec_id = SM.rec_id 
    INNER JOIN section_master AS SCM ON EM.section_rec_id = SCM.rec_id 
    INNER JOIN plant_master AS PM ON EM.plant_rec_id = PM.rec_id
    ORDER BY CAST(EM.employee_code As UNSIGNED )
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql) SO thread

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [manual for `CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), `INT` is not a type you can cast to. However, you can cast to `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`. Assuming you want the integer to be unsigned, use;

```
ORDER BY CAST(EM.employee_code As UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be one of the following:

```
CAST(EM.employee_code AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
CAST(EM.employee_code AS SIGNED INTEGER)
CAST(EM.employee_code AS UNSIGNED)
CAST(EM.employee_code AS SIGNED)
```

Contrary to other languages where the signed and unsigned modifiers are optional, in this case the keyword INTEGER is the one that is optional.