# Populating table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to populate a table using different .txt files, but every time that I want to include or add a new file the previous files get over written, not sure why this is happening.

This how I built the table - I am presuming that is something wrong with the primary key

```
CREATE TABLE BONDS(
CUSIP varchar(15) NOT NULL,
Price decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
Spot varchar(15),
Date_Priced varchar(55) not null,
Broker varchar(55) not null,
primary key(CUSIP)
);
```

This is how I import the .txt file

```
load data local infile 'c:/temp/test.txt'
into TABLE BONDS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should change your primary key column.

Your primary key should be an integer AUTO_INCREMENT'ed.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
);
```

[1] More on AUTO_INCREMENT https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

[2] More on LOAD DATA
https://tecfa.unige.ch/guides/mysql/man/manuel_LOAD_DATA.html

Comment: I did, but I got the following error: Error Code: 1467. Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

Comment: What happens if you declare your Primary Key as an int instead?

Comment: According to the following, it could be, that you need to update the table. Declaring the Primary key as int assumes an empty table. The following link shows how to both update the table on the first answer and how to sort your current table contents as well [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690926/failed-to-read-auto-increment-value-from-storage-engine-error-number-1467/17690982)

Comment: Nop, it didnt work, this what I did: 1.  I ran thisALTER TABLE bonds  AUTO_INCREMENT =1; then I upload the the file, didnt work, 2. then I switch the code, didnt work, 3. then I I create an index : CREATE INDEX id ON bonds(id);
 ALTER TABLE  bonds ORDER BY  id ; then I upload the .txt file, it didnt work either.

Comment: It could be that the PK needs to be an integer. Because you are effectively trying to add an integer on a string. Do you need to keep the field a VARCHAR? Can you create the table from scratch or do you need to keep your values?

Comment: I would try something like:

    CREATE TABLE BONDS(
    CUSIP int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Price decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
    Spot varchar(15),
    Date_Priced varchar(55) not null,
    Broker varchar(55) not null,
    primary key(CUSIP)
    );


If that does not solve your problem, perhaps look into something like

UPDATE tableName SET newCol = CAST(oldCol AS int);

which is mentioned here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18480609/13236364)

But, in that case, you will need to take care of the existing values.

Answer (score 0):

Just restructure your table add a new column id int, drop the previous primary key constraint and add id as a primary key and then use the below Query

```
load data local infile 'c:/temp/test.txt'
into TABLE BONDS (@dummy, CUSIP,Price,Spot,Date_Priced,Broker)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```