# adding value to IN variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to assign 21600000 to fromDate IF the value originally sent in is zero

Code that I have now is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportFreeCooling(
  IN fromDate VARCHAR (50),
  IN toDate   VARCHAR (50),
  IN timeZone VARCHAR (50)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE startDate VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE endDate   VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE startDateOriginal VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE mylogID   INT;
  DECLARE myItemId varchar (50);
  DECLARE myItemId2 varchar (50);
  DECLARE xHours varchar (50);
  DECLARE endHoursNull varchar(50);
  DECLARE endHoursNotNull varchar (50);
```

and of course the rest of the stored procedure. The rest is correct I just need to know how to change the fromDate if zero is what is sent in.

Comment: use a local variable to store the value you need, 21600000 if 0 given... PS: why using varchars?

Comment: using varchars due to the way the application processes - if i use timestamps or dates then it gives an odd result - believe me I have tried!...I have tried putting an IF fromDate = 0 then fromDate = 21600000 but that blew up on me! I am not sure what I need to set

Comment: I tried 
  IF fromDate = 0 THEN 
  SET @fromDate = '21600000';  but could not add an IF != 0 then fromDate  so what am I missing

Comment: basically this is what i need to code to do..... IF fromDate = 0 THEN 
  SET #fromDate = '21600000';
  IF fromDate > 0 THEN SET #fromDate = fromDate;
  SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(#fromDate/1000); ......but of course this is not working!  #date = @fromDate in above code as stackflow thinks everytime I use the 'at' symbol I am addressing a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested any of these but they may point you in the right direction.

OPTION 1: compare fromDate using a string comparison
...

```
IF fromDate = "0" THEN 
   SET @fromDate = '21600000'; 
ELSEIF fromDate > 0 THEN 
   ...
ELSE  
   ...
END IF;
```

OPTION 2: convert fromDate from varchar to int

```
DECLARE fromDateInt INT;

SELECT CONVERT(fromDate as SIGNED) INTO fromDateInt;
IF fromDate = 0 THEN 
   SET @fromDate = '21600000'; 
...
```

[Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Also, you may want to check/handle:
1.  Could fromDate be a float?
2.  Could fromDate be NULL?

Comment: I tried    IF fromDate = "0" THEN 
    SET #fromDate = '21600000'; 
   ELSE
    SET #fromDate = fromDate
  END IF;  and it gave me an error that says there is a ; expected before the END I also tried  IF fromDate = "0" THEN 
    SET #fromDate = '21600000'; 
   ELSEIF fromDate > 0 THEN
    SET #fromDate = fromDate
  END IF;  and it gave me the same error.....no I do not want to convert it to an int and no fromDate could not be null or a float -

Comment: I edited to include a ";" after "END IF".  Is that your issue?

Comment: no I tried adding a ; to END IF - so END IF; gives me an error .... it is saying it expected a ; before the END but I know that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code actually required a ; at the end of the set statement and the end of the if statment.

```
IF firstRowDate > startDateOriginal THEN SET startDateOriginal = firstRowDate; END IF;
```