# How to cast varchar into int properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've prepared sql query like this

```
UPDATE Towar
JOIN TowarZamowienie ON Towar.Tow_id = TowarZamowienie.Tow_id
SET Tow_ilosc = Tow_ilosc - CAST(TowZam_ilosc AS UNSIGNED);
```

and it returns me  Modified records: 0. I will admit that I've got records in database

Here are my tables:

```
TowarZamowienie 

1   TowZam_id         int(19) AUTO_INCREMENT   
2   Tow_id            int(255)            
3   Zam_id            int(255)             
4   TowZam_ilosc      varchar(10)
```

---

```
Towar

1     Tow_id           int(255)
2     Tow_ilosc        int(6)
```

Here is my schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/981b4/1

Comment: Check this out... Possible duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql

Comment: @chris_techno25 it is not duplicate becouse i've got no error there.

Comment: show your example data or fiddle if possible !

Comment: Ahhh I see, well then echo_Me is right. It will definitely be easier if you show us an example data :)

Comment: @echo_Me here it is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/981b4/1

Comment: @chris_techno25 look up

Comment: I know i have got 0os but it should be work for 1 am I right?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing numbers in varchar columns.

Comment: @user3310883 I checked sqlfiddle. I used Select * from Towar and Select * from TowarZamowienie. The first row that pops out, you'd want Tow_ilosc to be equal to 100 right? Coz 100-0=100. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, but when TowZam_ilosc equals 1 it should be 99

Comment: look at this, how does it works now. look at this i59.tinypic.com/mif3fa.png it should change values where tow_id is the same as tow_id from towarzamowienie i60.tinypic.com/2i7sdu8.png It is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you making wrong in the ON clause

try this

```
    ON Towar.Tow_id = TowarZamowienie.TowZam_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9965/1)

Comment: look at this http://i59.tinypic.com/mif3fa.png it should change values where tow_id is the same as tow_id from towarzamowienie http://i60.tinypic.com/2i7sdu8.png

Comment: @user3310883 i have seen the images but you have Twozam_ilosc is 0 according to two_zam 5 , how will this be 99 ? look this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8596ce/1)

Comment: In this case it should return 100-0 =100, no change

Comment: but when TowZam_ilosc is for example 1 it should return 99 in Towar.Tow_ilosc

Comment: I don't get why Towar with Tow_id 16 and more has changed.. The only one Towar modified in this case should be Towar with Tow_id 5

Comment: dude i really dont understand you , look this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e61702/1) i changed just the SET .... with -1 . your query is good , you didnt get twoyam 5 to change because its equivalent value of twozam_ilosc is 0 .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  UPDATE Towar
 JOIN 
    TowarZamowienie ON Towar.Tow_id = TowarZamowienie.TowZam_id
 SET 
    Tow_ilosc = Tow_ilosc - CAST(TowZam_ilosc AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: value have to be casted from string to int firstly

Answer (score 0):

Why not "cast" the Integer to Varchar? What if the Varchar has really 10 chars and the Integer will expect just 6 numbers? Try this:

```
CAST(Tow_ilosc as CHAR(10))
```

or

```
CONVERT(Tow_ilosc, CHAR(10))
```

or just use `like` in the where clause

```
WHERE Tow_ilosc LIKE TowZam_ilosc
```

(I don't like like)^^

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Towar, TowarZamowienie
SET Towar.Tow_ilosc = Towar.Tow_ilosc - CAST(TowarZamowienie.TowZam_ilosc AS UNSIGNED)
WHERE Towar.Tow_id = TowarZamowienie.TowZam_id;
```

--OR

```
UPDATE Towar
JOIN TowarZamowienie ON Towar.Tow_id = TowarZamowienie.TowZam_id
SET Tow_ilosc = Tow_ilosc - CAST(TowZam_ilosc AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: Try using code formatting for the samples you post. Makes it easier to read. Thanks :)