# Ruby // Random number between range, ensure uniqueness against others existing stored ones

Tags: ruby, random, integer

Currently trying to generate a random number in a specific range;
and ensure that it would be unique against others stored records.

Using Mysql. Could be like an id, incremented; but can't be it.

Currently testing other existing records in an 'expensive' manner;
but I'm pretty sure that there would be a clean 1/2 lines of code to use

Currently using :

```
test = 0
Order.all.each do |ord|
  test = (0..899999).to_a.sample.to_s.rjust(6, '0')
  if Order.find_by_number(test).nil? then
    break
  end
end
return test
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: @toro2k edited with an example. Let's say I'm not sure about how to  make a quick and clean test and recall the random 'generator' if  already existing

Comment: @Ben, I have post my answer. It takes performance into account and since you are going to use it quit often I guess, you should try it.

Comment: yep; clean one and quite understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your are my one-line solution. It is also the quicker one since calls `.pluck` to retrieve the numbers from the Order table. `.select` instantiates an "Order" object for every record (that is very costly and unnecessary) while `.pluck` does not. It also avoids to iterate again each object with a `.map` to get the "number" field. We can avoid the second `.map` as well if we convert, using `CAST` in this case, to a numeric value from the database.

```
(Array(0...899999) - Order.pluck("CAST('number' AS UNSIGNED)")).sample.to_s.rjust(6, '0')
```

Comment: what is the CAST UNSIGNED used for ? (I'll go to the docs mysql to check but you seem to be very well in the know)

Comment: It is the safest way to convert a varchar into a kind of integer value in MySQL (since "order.number" is in varchar). Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql

Comment: You mean the safest used in this function' scope or globally ? My 'number' field is an integer... but you'll say that an integer field can't be zerofilled (000018 for example) ? Got to check on my side

Comment: I(we) though that your 'number' field was a `varchar` because in your example you are converting it to `string`: `to_s.rjust(6, '0')`. If it is an integer you can remove the `CAST`.

Comment: Yes sure, I have to assume not being an expert on this one and not being that accurate. Thanks a lot for your very clean answer, helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can do something like below :

```
def uniq_num_add(arr)
 loop do
   rndm = rand(1..15)  # I took this range as an example
    # random number will be added to the array, when the number will 
    # not be present
    break arr<< "%02d" % rndm unless arr.include?(rndm)
  end  
end  

array = []

3.times do
 uniq_num_add(array)
end  

array # => ["02", "15", "04"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
# gets all existing IDs
existing_ids = Order.all.select(:number).map(&:number).map(&:to_i)

# removes them from the acceptable range
available_numbers = (0..899999).to_a - existing_ids

# choose one (which is not in the DB)
available_numbers.sample.to_s.rjust(6, '0')
```

Comment: available_numberS (can't edit this just one letter thing). but yeah, thx !

Comment: @Uri, you solution works and is fine but this code is quite inefficient `Order.all.select(:number).map(&:number).map(&:to_i)` for serveral reasons.