# How to sort MySQL query records from big to small numbers

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sort my records from big to small numbers, here are my example records:

```
id   name   view   like
1   name1    5      1
2   name2    2      4
3   name3    41     3
4   name4    6      31
5   name5    1      2
```

For example, I want the order the records like this (i.e. ordered by the field named `like`):

```
id   name   view   like
4   name4    6      31
2   name2    2      4
3   name3    41     3
5   name5    1      2
1   name1    5      1
```

I tried this query...

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY like DESC
```

...but the query result is like this now:

```
id   name   view   like
2   name2    2      4
3   name3    41     3
4   name4    6      31
5   name5    1      2
1   name1    5      1
```

So, what is the correct query for what I want?

Comment: What is the data type of filed `like`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are storing the numerical value of `like` in a string format; either `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`. This will result in the alphabetical style ordering that you can see (imagine 1 as A, 2 as B, etc.. and then order the results as words).

Change the datatype of the column to a numerical format like `INT` and the query should behave as expected.

If you cannot change the datatype of the column then I would suggest casting it in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY CAST(`like` AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY CAST(`like` AS SIGNED) DESC
```

if `like` can be negative.

I find this more readable and controlled than `+0`, but Abhik beat me to it :)

Comment: typecasting in mysql is also answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql

In the context of this question, the typecasting should probably look something like this:

`select ... cast(\`like\` as unsigned) as liked order by liked`

Comment: @andkrup Fair enough, I quite like that approach but it is not necessary to get the results.. N.B. this would also apply to Abhik's answer below.

Comment: no disagreement at all :) I just thought that the cast function needed mentioning as well since type juggling was the issue

Answer (score 4):

`like` is a `reserved` word in `mysql`

You can escape it by using backticks; ``

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `like` DESC
```

Comment: This does not answer the question the OP is getting the data but not in the desired way.

Comment: If data type is `int` then answer is okk . and OP not specify the `datatype` of `like field`

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you choose wrong datatype for storing integer data and you might have have choosen varchar for this.

You need to convert the string to numbers for ordering

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY `like`+0 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a reserved word as a field name. Change it to `likes` and then you can directly fire this query...

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY likes DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the datatype of like column i think it is not Integer if it is not so please ALTER the table