# How to sum varchar datatype by converting varchar into float

Tags: mysql, database

I have a column 'amount' which is in '`varchar`' datatype in my table 'tbl1'. Now I have to calculate total amount of that column (I know I can modify column for my table but I have to follow some procedure to keep it as '`varchar`' . but result must be return in `float` datatype.

I have written following query as:

```
Select sum(amount) from tbl1;
```

it gives an error :

> Conversion failed when converting varchar datatype into int

so tried this one query also:

```
select sum(convert(float, amount)) from tbl1;
```

but I got error.

Comment: Provide some sample data

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql

Comment: It seems there is nothing wrong with your code but with your data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT sum(CAST(amount AS UNSIGNED)) FROM tbl1
```

Note that `UNSIGNED` and `SIGNED` are used for Integer. If your data may contain decimal values then you can instead try to use `decimal` like this:

```
SELECT sum(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(10,2))) FROM tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have an error casting because I have values like - into the fields

I found this solution that has different value types
[How to Sum a varchar(20) Column](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/09c2f692-b2c6-415a-8515-e8ee4319ac6e/how-to-sum-a-varchar20-column?forum=transactsql)

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
   keycol INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   datacol VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES(1, 'a');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES(2, '10');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES(3, '5');
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES(4, NULL);

SELECT SUM(
       CASE WHEN datacol NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
            THEN CAST(datacol AS BIGINT)
            ELSE 0
       END) AS total
FROM Foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply do this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount::REAL) FROM tbl1;
```

For PostgreSQL.