# Eloquent Left Join, getting unexpected result

Tags: php, join, eloquent, left-join

Overview:

I have two tables called `event_meta` and `options`.

**Options:**

[image]

**Event Meta:**

[image]

I have a table called Event Meta where the sub information of specific event are stored. Now what I want to happen is to connect the `event_meta` and `options` table using `leftjoin` in eloquent.

Here's my code for that.

```
public function getMetaValue($key) {

    $event_meta = $this->hasOne('Core\Event\EventMeta', 'event_id')
        ->leftjoin('options', 'options.id', '=', 'event_meta.meta_value')
        ->where('meta_key', '=', $key)
        ->first();

    // If Option[table] value is empty, it will retrieve for Event Meta's[table] value, else It will return false.
    return (empty($event_meta->value)) ? (empty($event_meta->meta_value)) ? false : $event_meta->meta_value : $event_meta->value;
}
```

Now the problem is.. If I retrieve the `meta_key` logo...

[image]

It retrieves the value from options table called `Top Up` that has the id of `6`

[image]

Notice the first character in `meta_key` logo's `meta_value` it has the same value in option's id.

[image]

I tried changing the `6` to `7`, the value's change and it retrieves the Option's `Vending POS`.

Any solution for this? This isn't supposed to happen though. Since logo's value is waaay longer than the actual id of options.

--- Edit ---

My attempts fixing it while waiting for help.

**1st Attempt:**

I tried this solution just for the sake it might be fixed. Still does not work.

```
public function getMetaValue($key) {

    $event_meta = $this->hasOne('Core\Event\EventMeta', 'event_id')
        ->leftjoin('options', function($query) {
            $query->on('options.id', '=', 'event_meta.meta_value');
        })->where('meta_key', '=', $key)
        ->first();
    return (empty($event_meta->value)) ? (empty($event_meta->meta_value)) ? false : $event_meta->meta_value : $event_meta->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer to this question! It's not because it's Eloquent but it's really on MYSQL query that has a problem. Well technically my fault for not converting it to same type.

Thanks to this guy's help who answered my related question here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32647701/1699388

> Cast your numeric options.id field to the same type as
>   event_meta.meta_value in your JOIN.

So what I did is I converted my `options.id` AS TEXT to have the same type as `event_meta.meta_value` in my left join query.

So I casted it like this

```
$leftjoin->on(DB::raw('CAST(options.id AS CHAR(1000))'), '=', 'event_meta.meta_value');
```

Reference for Cast (SO ANSWER): https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127022/1699388

So what it looks like is this!

```
public function getMetaValue($key) {

    $event_meta = $this->hasOne('Core\Event\EventMeta', 'event_id')
        ->leftjoin('options', function($leftjoin) {
            $leftjoin->on(DB::raw('CAST(options.id AS CHAR(1000))'), '=', 'event_meta.meta_value');
        })->where('meta_key', '=', $key)
        ->first();

    return (empty($event_meta->value)) ? (empty($event_meta->meta_value)) ? false : $event_meta->meta_value : $event_meta->value;
}
```

Second Solution is from my boss in work (Credits to him). What he did is he added another `AND` on leftjoin to convert `event_meta.meta_value` to an integer by just multiplying it to 1.

```
public function getMetaValue($key) {

    $event_meta = $this->hasOne('Core\Event\EventMeta', 'event_id')
        ->leftjoin('options', function($leftjoin) {
            $leftjoin->on('options.id', '=', 'event_meta.meta_value');
            $leftjoin->on(DB::raw('CONCAT("", event_meta.meta_value * 1)'), '=', 'event_meta.meta_value');                
        })->where('meta_key', '=', $key)
        ->first();

    return (empty($event_meta->value)) ? (empty($event_meta->meta_value)) ? false : $event_meta->meta_value : $event_meta->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Value insert of logo meta key value in worng table please correct Entry.
Your logo value insert in options table  and option id insert in Event Meta: table 

option table 
===========
id      type        value
11      logo        6b3bca56b9c693db313b667ae77507291b47ddd55e382..




Event Meta:
============
id      event_id        meta_key    meta_value
29      1               logo        11


Now You retrive the Meta_key logo and use Your query so give perfect Result 
<?php
public function getMetaValue($key) {

    $event_meta = $this->hasOne('Core\Event\EventMeta', 'event_id')
        ->leftjoin('options', function($query) {
            $query->on('options.id', '=', 'event_meta.meta_value');
        })->where('meta_key', '=', $key)
        ->first();
    return (empty($event_meta->value)) ? (empty($event_meta->meta_value)) ? false : $event_meta->meta_value : $event_meta->value;
}
?>
```