# Left Join connecting primary key to normal column causes havoc

Tags: php, mysql

Link below is related to my question:

[Eloquent Left Join, getting unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643803/eloquent-left-join-getting-unexpected-result)

Here's my table structure just to give an overview.

**Options:**

[image]

**Event Meta:**

[image]

Well, it really is the same problem but I thought it's because of Eloquent. When I tried to use PDO querying the problem on my link. It still does the same.

```
$query = $db->prepare(
    "   SELECT      * FROM event_meta a
        LEFT JOIN   options b ON b.id = a.meta_value
        WHERE       a.meta_key = 'logo'
"); $query->execute();

$object = $query->fetchObject();

echo $object->value, '<br>';
echo $object->meta_value;
```

So what I did is, I have a table called `event_meta` and trying to join the `options` table to connect them I use `b.id` and for `event_meta` is `a.meta_value`

What I want to happen on my end is to retrieve the `options.value` first to check if it's empty. If it is empty, I will get the `event_meta.meta_value`'s value to output it.

So for example on my query above, I want to get the `meta_key` called logo. It should get the output of an image name. But since I'm connected to `options` table it should get the `options.value`. When outputting the `options.value` it should be blank. Since the `meta_value` of logo does not equals to any `options.id`. But it's retrieving the `Top Up` value.

Comment: @Moderator, I'm trying to connect both of them, just giving a visual look of what my table looks like. Since every first character (Not the whole value) of `meta_value` is connecting to my `options id`.

Comment: so you need all in `options` table and less in `meta_value`

Comment: Not all really, just copying the select query on what is Eloquent trying to do when querying the data. So what I need both `meta_value` of event_meta and `value` of options. I need to check if value is empty, if it is I will have to get the meta_value

Comment: @BrianCoolidge: Please suggest what you required..1st you need only common rows from both tables where meta_key=logo or all rows from meta_value where meta_key=logo and corresponding rows from option table.....also as per meta_key='logo' your meta_value prmary key value should be 29 not 8...

Comment: @ZafarMalik, I'm connecting left join in options as `event_meta.meta_value` not `event_meta.id` though. I revised my question.

Comment: @BrianCoolidge: show what output you are getting and what you need...as per your query you should get output as per following ---- 29,1,'logo','6b3b........',NULL,NULL,NULL........also you are joining both tables based on meta_value which seems either longvarchar or text type field, so it will kill the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Top Up" `options.id` value is 6. The numeric value of your (presumably binary image) logo value in `event_meta.meta_value` is 6, because it starts "6b3b.....". That's why they're comparing equal.

When comparing a numeric field with a character field, MySQL will take the numeric value of the character field and compare it with the number. The thing you may be missing is that the numeric value of a character field like "123abc3478uweefauiofyh3489h" in MySQL is 123.

Cast your numeric `options.id` field to the same type as `event_meta.meta_value` in your JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
$query = $db->prepare(
            "SELECT *
            FROM options
            LEFT OUTER JOIN event_meta
            ON options.id=event_meta.meta_value
            WHERE event_meta.meta_key= 'event_package';");
```

Comment: I changed `event_package` to `logo`. Still produces the same result. I'm getting the `Top Up` value from `options table` It should be blank though. Since the value from `logo` is like loooong.

Comment: I revised my question. Please see it. :)