# MySQL Stored Procedure Issue #1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

This little one gives me syntax problem, i cant solve that i'll appreciate that.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE procedure kullanicibilgicek
(
p_kadi varchar(50)
)
begin
declare v_sonuc INT;
if(CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(p_kadi)) > 4)
then
    if exists (select kullanicilar.kullaniciadi, kullanicilar.sifre from kullanicilar where kullaniciadi = p_kadi)
    then
    select id, upper(left(ad,1))+ right(ad, char_length(rtrim(ad)) -1), upper(left(soyad,1))+ right(soyad, char_length(rtrim(soyad)) -1), yetki, upper(left(kullaniciadi,1))+ right(kullaniciadi, char_length(rtrim(kullaniciadi)) -1), kullanicilar.sifre from kullanicilar where kullaniciadi = p_kadi;
    else
    set v_sonuc = 0;
    select v_sonuc;
    end if;

else
    if exists (select kullanicilar.kullaniciadi, kullanicilar.sifre from kullanicilar where id = Cast(p_kadi as int))
    then
    select id, upper(left(ad,1))+ right(ad, char_length(rtrim(ad)) -1), upper(left(soyad,1))+ right(soyad, char_length(rtrim(soyad)) -1), yetki, upper(left(kullaniciadi,1))+ right(kullaniciadi, char_length(rtrim(kullaniciadi)) -1), kullanicilar.sifre from kullanicilar where id = cast(p_kadi as int);

    else
    set v_sonuc = 0;
    select v_sonuc;
    end if;
end if;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near `'int))
>       then
>       select id, upper(left(ad,1))+ right(ad, char_length(rtrim(ad)) -1'` at line 18

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Comment: As the in the linked question suggests, use `UNSIGNED` instead of `int`.