# Why SUM(`column`) returns a string instead of an integer?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sum, sqldatatypes

I'm using Laravel and have a query that selects using `DB::raw()` `SUM()` of a column:

`DB::raw("SUM(points) as game_points")`

I have installed [mysqldn](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) and AFAIK Laravel uses `PDO`.

But `game_points` is a string, no matter what type of the column is. (*It's an integer column*)

Also if I do:

`DB::raw("COUNT(id) as foo_bar")`

`foo_bar` is returned as an integer.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's neither Laravel or PDO issue.

According to [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html), `SUM()` returns a `DECIMAL` value for exact-value arguments (`integer` or `DECIMAL`). And the only way to represent `DECIMAL` type in PHP is **string**, for two reasons:

- it can overflow the PHP's int type, being bigger than PHP_INT_MAX.
- also, in case the returned value being a decimal number, it can lose precision due to [inherently imprecise nature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) of floating point numbers (for example DECIMAL(10,2) can accurately store 0.1, while the closest thing php's native float-type can store is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 )

due to these precautions the value is returned as string, and you are supposed to convert it manually according to the expecting value - either using standard PHP type casting or using some dedicated math functions such as bcmath.

Comment: Interesting, so that's why `CAST(SUM(column) AS INTEGER)` still works and returns an integer.

Comment: as of at least mysql 8.0 AS INTEGER throws error. so u need to write AS UNSIGNED. for [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert that string to an integer by using `CONVERT(INT, game_points)`

According to [bugs.mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13730), `sum()` returns a `NEWDECIMAL` datatype, which is equivalent to `string` in php, while `count()` returns an `integer` datatype.

Comment: I know what to do to convert/cast them to integers. I'm asking why is this happening. :)

Comment: this is happening becos your database is either a VHARCHA or something else but not INTEGER or FLOAT