# Node.js: PostgreSQL's SUM() returns a string instead of an integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

In MySQL, it's because [`SUM()` returns a `DECIMAL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36057647/9157799). From [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
sum(smallint) → bigint  
sum(integer) → bigint  
sum(bigint) → numeric  
sum(numeric) → numeric  
sum(real) → real  
sum(double precision) → double precision  
sum(interval) → interval  
sum(money) → money
     Computes the sum of the non-null input values.
```

Since I'm calculating the sum of integers, therefore it should return an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Postgres' `bigint` is up to 2<sup>64</sup> which is larger than JavaScript's `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2<sup>53</sup>)](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4064#issuecomment-291432582), therefore it's usually [represented with string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39176670/9157799).

We can use JS' [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or cast `bigint` to `integer` directly:

```sql
SELECT CAST(SUM(salary) as INTEGER)
FROM employee;
```