# PHP Mysqli query comparing string-type number field to an integer

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where one of the fields is for `bathrooms` and users usually input `1` or `3` or sometimes `1.1` which means 1 full bathroom and 1 half bathroom so I couldn't store this field as number, integer or double, or decimal. I had to store them as text.

My question is, how can I do this in a query if I wanted to pull only those records who's bathrooms is greater than 3 or something? I am looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM agentdb WHERE converttointeger(bathrooms) => 3
```

Obviously `converttointeger` is not valid but is there a way to achieve this? I tried searching and Googling but I keep getting the wrong results or wrong topic.

Comment: First, you shouldn't store data like this. Does `CAST(bathrooms AS DECIMAL)` helps?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM agentdb WHERE CAST(bathrooms AS INT) >=3` ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I can't use decimal. Decimal reads 1.1 as 1 and 10% of 1. The users input 1.1 bathrooms meaning 1 and a half bathroom. This is already how they been doing it for years so I can't change that :(

Comment: Store it one way but display it another. Users won't see that secretly you're doing what makes sense and storing `1.1` as `1.5`

Comment: @Terminus that makes sense. I might just do it that way.:)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use text converted to integers. Store the values as numbers with a decimal portions such as `decimal`. Then you can use the `>` comparison with no need for casting.

I would use `DECIMAL(2,1)`, meaning 2 digits, including 1 decimal digit. "1.1" would be saved as `1.1`, not `1.10`

Alternative: You could also have two table fields: `full_baths` and `half_baths`, each of type `tinyint` or `smallint`. When your user enters "1.1" just split it before storing

```
$baths = $_POST['bathrooms'];// eg: "2.1"
$baths_arr = explode(".",$baths); // eg: [2,1]

$full = $half = 0; //full baths, half baths
if(!empty($baths_arr)):
    $full = (int)$baths_arr[0]; //we explicitly convert to integer
    $half = empty($baths_arr[1])? 0: (int)$baths_arr[1];
endif;
```

Then you can save `$full` and `$half` in their respective columns

Comment: Because users input bathroom counts as "1.1" meaning 1 full bathroom and 1 half bathroom. If decimal, this will be read as "1.10" or 1 + 0.1. Therefore 1.1 + 1.1 should result to 3 but in Decimal it will result to 2.2

Comment: Does any part of your script require you to do 1.1 + 1.1 ?  The only requirement you mentioned was how to compare two numbers to find which is greater (in your OP: `bathrooms >= 3`)

Comment: Sorry, my initial requirement was explained that I needed to compare a number stored as string as a number VS a number. Which is why I added that it should be something like "WHERE converttointeger(bathrooms) => 3" or semething that converts the bathrooms (text type) to integer to compare it to a number like 3 or 3.1

Comment: The solutions we gave you would allow you to make a comparison without worry so your initial requirement is met no? In your comment to my solution, you introduced the prospect of doing `1.1 +  1.1`. My follow-up question was: When would you need to do that? (by the way I edited my answer with an alternative)

Comment: Yes somewhere along the process they will eventually be compared as 1.1 + 1.1 when I need to add the total bathrooms being offered per groups of rooms. I will try your solution sir :)

Comment: If you expect to perform arithmetic operations (not just compare as in your initial Q), your best bet is to use two table fields, one for full and the other for half-baths as in my alternative.  If you find it helpful, let me know with positive feedback. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
SELECT * FROM agentdb WHERE CAST(bathrooms AS SIGNED) >= 3

I got the answer from here:
[Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Comment: This worked, my solution was `CAST(bathrooms AS DECIMAL(2,1)) >= ?`

Comment: Sorry my bad, this has problems. 3.0 >= 3.1 is returning true

Answer (score 0):

Store them as floats so that you can have decimals but keep them as numeric.

Comment: Even better, store it as `DECIMAL(3,1)` or `DECIMAL(2,1)`. You don't need `FLOAT`'s precisions.

Answer (score 0):

'bathrooms' data = { 1, 3, {3 < int}}

You need only 3 or 3 over integer.
Conversely Think!
You don't need '1' data. 
So...

```
SELECT * FROM agentdb WHERE bathrooms <> '1'
```

And, Casted columnn is not working index.