# How to get a numeric signature of a CHAR column in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a CHAR or VARCHAR column in MySql, what I need is to convert it to a number so it can be summed up. For example, if the column name is CHAR1, the SELECT would be:

```
SELECT SUM(ConvertToNumber(CHAR1)) from TABLE1
```

The function `ConvertToNumber` just needs to convert to a number, it doesn't matter which number as long as it always converts to the same.

Is this feasible with native or user defined functions?

UPDATE: To be clear, the values of CHAR1 can be any string of alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Have you googled "MySQL convert CHAR to INT"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Comment: cast is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is convert the column to the hexadecimal format, and then convert this result into base 10 to get an integer.

```
SELECT SUM(CONV(HEX(CHAR1), 16, 10)) FROM TABLE1;
```

For instance:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (CHAR1) VALUES ("foo"), ("bar"), ("baz");

/* "int" value for each entry */
SELECT CONV(HEX(CHAR1), 16, 10) FROM TABLE1;

6713199
6447474
6447482

/* sum of the int values */
SELECT SUM(CONV(HEX(CHAR1), 16, 10)) FROM TABLE1

19608155
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(CHAR1 AS UNSIGNED) FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: From what I understand, the OP would like to convert any value to an integer, for instance values that do not represent or even contain any digit.

Comment: That's correct, the column value could be any alphanumeric character