# how to sort numerical data in sql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have data which has **5000 rows with 40 columns**. I want to sort the data according to the first column in the row, which contains the *id* value of the particular row. The values in the *id* column are like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,.....100,101,102.....1000,1001.....` 
when I use a SQL statement with the order clause `ORDER by id ASC`.

Data is sorting in this manner`..1,10,100,1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,101.102,103,........`

But I want the data to be in ascending order like: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13.....`

This is the statement:
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM masterdb ORDER BY id ASC");`

Comment: The query code you shown will give you exact output:- `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13..........`

Comment: Your query is correct as soon as your ids exact column is `id` or you id must not be numeric type

Comment: column id isnt numeric

Comment: but my output is displaying like this 1,10,100,1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,101.102,103

Comment: SELECT * FROM masterdb ORDER BY cast(id as int) ASC

Comment: Thanks @kazz ,my coumn id i gave is varchar,when i changed it to int,its working.

Comment: You have to check datatype of your id I think It may varchar.

Comment: AFAIK [you can't cast varchar to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql) in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider making your `id` column a numeric type if you expect to have the need to often sort numerically.  That being said, one workaround would be to cast the `id` column to a numeric type and then sort using this:

```
SELECT *
FROM masterdb
ORDER BY CAST(id AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: I want to keep my id coumn as varchar , because sometimes my id contains alpabets also like TNDIDTNC120134,TNDIDTNC120135,TNDIDTNC120136....along with the numeric id's like 1,2,3,4,5,6...In this situation ,how can i sort all the alphanumerics in the starting and the numerics at the end.

Comment: @sasi Does the `id` column _always_ have the format of letters followed by numbers?  Furthermore, is the _width_ of the letter portion always the same?  Update your question showing the full extent of what this column might look like.

Comment: Sometimes id is characters and numericals and sometimes only numericals. The width of the id is always of this length ITNMWROCT160010 ,but sometimes its lesser than this with just numerical values like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,......100,101,102,103....1000

Comment: If the width of the id is always some length, but sometimes less, then it isn't always some length.  Update your question and _clearly_ show us the range of values which the `id` column can take.

Comment: The range of the value is 15 and if id is an alphanumeric like 'ITNMWROCT160010' it is fixed length for all alphanumeric entries,if it is only numeric like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....

Comment: Please update your question showing us what the range is. I won't comment further until this has been done.