# Mysql Order by number dont humanize output

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

my mysql query dont humanize the ORDER BY.

```
SELECT COUNT(level) as count, level
from logtest
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY level;
```

Sample:

```
6
5
5
5
13
0
```

The correct would be

```
13
6
5
5
5
0
```

any help?

Comment: please share you MySql query

Comment: SELECT COUNT(level) as count, level from logtest GROUP BY level ORDER BY level;

Comment: you mean `order by cast(level as unsigned) desc`?  The issue appears to be your data is text when you need it to be numeric to sort correctly.  so... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql

Comment: if you want your data to be sorted as a string, than you have to store it as a string, not a number

Comment: all is like string in this table. thank you guys. "cast" work for me. I will save this command for later use too! thank you folks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(level) as count, level
FROM logtest
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY cast(level as unsigned);
```

Near Dup of: [Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Not quite a dup because the issues on sort is that it's sorting by a text field (my guess is level is of character type) when you want it to sort by numeric type... so just cast which the above link describes how.