# How to make mysql expression to return integer value?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have two tables in mysql as below:

`Table1` holds the questions

```
qid  tid  qtype 
101    1    1
102    1    2
103    1    3
104    1    4
```

Here `qtype` is question type where `qtype` 1 and 2 accept numeric values and 3 and 4 accept string. I have declared `qtype` as `varchar` column.

Table2 holds the answers

```
sid qid  qtype qanswer
1    101    1     10
1    102    2     20
1    103    3     o1
1    104    4     o2
```

there are rows for every question for every 'sid'.

I have selected data in below fashion using following query:

```
select a.sid, MAX(CASE WHEN (a.qid = 101) THEN if(a.qtype in(1,2),cast(a.qanswer as unsigned),a.qanswer) ELSE NULL END) AS '101' ,
MAX(CASE WHEN (a.qid = 102) THEN if(a.qtype in(1,2),cast(a.qanswer as unsigned),a.qanswer) ELSE NULL END) AS '102' ,
MAX(CASE WHEN (a.qid = 103) THEN if(a.qtype in(1,2),cast(a.qanswer as unsigned),a.qanswer) ELSE NULL END) AS '103' ,
MAX(CASE WHEN (a.qid = 104) THEN if(a.qtype in(1,2),cast(a.qanswer as unsigned),a.qanswer) ELSE NULL END) AS '104' from Table2 a join Table1 b on a.qtype = b.qtpe where b.tid = 1

sid 101 102 103 104
1    10  20  o1  o2
2    30  15  o2  o1
```

I wanted to select `qtype` 1 and 2 as integer so I used below statement in my query:

```
if(qtype in (1,2),cast(qanswer as unsigned),qanswer)
```

I am not getting answer for `qtype` 1 and 2 as desired. 
I took reference from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

I also tried `convert` instead of cast but got same result.
How can I cast `qtype` 1 and 2 as integer?

How to return integer value from mysql expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a *statement*:

```
if(qtype in (1, 2), cast(qanswer as unsigned), qanswer)
```

This is an *expression*.  An expression returns a scalar value with a single type.  MySQL needs to decide if the returned type is `unsigned` or `varchar`, because it must choose one for the entire expression.

MySQL would appear to be choose the string type.

Comment: How do i make mysql to choose integer value rather than string value.

Comment: @AMahajan . . . That would be a different question from the one you asked.  You should ask new questions as a *question* rather than a *comment*.  Provide sample data and desired results.