# How to convert string to integer or double using sql queries

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and I want to convert a string to a number because I have to select the max no between them.

- In my database I have two columns `item code` and `item name`, both are of varchar type
- so the `item code` I want it to convert in `int` or `double`

[image: This is my table in database]

here I am writing query as `SELECT MAX(itemcode) FROM ITEMMASTER` it is giving me result as `603` I want it to give me `2402` as this one is the maximum

Any help or guidance will be appreciated

Comment: @DaleBurrell it is showing error i am using mysql 5.1

Comment: this is the error i am getting  `check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'int)) from ITEMMASTER' at line 1`

Comment: And as you add additional information through answering questions, please add that information directly to your question so that you question contains all the required information for an answer to be provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Comment: @dheerajkumar I have added demo to my answer. Have a look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following query.

```
select Max(cast(itemcode as UNSIGNED)) from ITEMMASTER
```

For your reference : `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast`

Comment: hey i am getting error `check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'int)) from ITEMMASTER' at line 1`

Comment: Can you tell me the mySQL version

Comment: i am using version 5.1

Comment: Unsigned numbers do not have the minus sign. Unsigned number can be only positive or zero (e.g. 123, 0). Signed numbers can be also negative (e.g. -42).

Answer (score 0):

You can try MySQL CAST() function is as follows:

```
CAST(expression AS TYPE);

CREATE TABLE ITEMMASTERTest  (
    ItemCode VARCHAR(255),
    ItemName VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO ITEMMASTERTest (ItemCode,ItemName) VALUES ('2402', 'A');
INSERT INTO ITEMMASTERTest (ItemCode,ItemName) VALUES ('333', 'B');
INSERT INTO ITEMMASTERTest (ItemCode,ItemName) VALUES ('603', 'C');
INSERT INTO ITEMMASTERTest (ItemCode,ItemName) VALUES ('1001', 'C');

Select Max(CAST(ItemCode AS SIGNED)) FROM ITEMMASTERTest ;
```

You can check the live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/BUU52586)

Comment: i have tried but it didn't  work....can you help me with query which will give me max item code after conversion as i have also attached my db image