# how can i fix (You have an error in your SQL syntax..)

Tags: mysql

hi i have the following query

```
   SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(battles,';',1) AS INT)) from battles;
```

the query work well in my localhost (XAMMP) , But anywhere else it gives me this error

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT)) from battles' at line 1
```

example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e19e8c/2

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql CAST as INT is invalid

Comment: Use unsigned rather than INT ,`SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(battles,';',1) AS unsigned)) from battles;` INT IS INVALID

Comment: Note that XAMPP is using MariaDB. `CAST('123string' AS INT)` works for MariaDB but not for (oracles) MySQL. Use `CAST('123string' AS SIGNED)`, which works on both systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INT isn't a valid type for a MySQL CAST.  Try SIGNED INTEGER.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert (CONVERT and CAST support the same types)