# How to cast varchar into int - SQL Error: '=' cannot be applied to varchar, bigint

Tags: sql, presto

I have a list of product collection ids in the form of `varchar` datatype.

Referring to a sample structure below.. I would like to retrieve the item names of collection id (pro_col_id) 3453, 3454, 3455.

[image]

My query is as follows:

```
select pro_col_id, name
from collections_table 
where pro_col_id in (3453, 3454, 3455);
```

When I ran this query, I got an error

> SQL Error: '=' cannot be applied to varchar, bigint

So I tried to cast `pro_col_id` as int like this:

```
select pro_col_id, name
from collections_table 
where cast(pro_col_id as int) in (3453, 3454, 3455);
```

but I still get the same error. Does anyone know what is the issue causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Comment: [specifically, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127022/3536236)

Answer (score 3):

If the values are strings, then the comparisons should be strings:

```
select pro_col_id, name
from collections_table 
where pro_col_id in ('3453', '3454', '3455');
```

If this does not fix your problem, then the issue is not the `where` clause.  One possibility is that `collections_table` is not really a table but is a view, and something is amiss in the view.

Comment: What if you wanted to query HTTP status code within a range? Listing them up doesn't sound like fun, assuming the range is big enough.