# Using CAST in MYSQL Query, It works in localhost, But in the server not working

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql using cast, I wrote the query like

Accnno - varchar

`SELECT * FROM books where category = 'Book' ORDER BY CAST(Accnno AS int) DESC LIMIT 0,10`

The above query is working fine in the localhost, But is not working in the server, It shows error like

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int) DESC LIMIT 0,10' at line 1

Comment: Are you really sure it works in the localhost? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=0057d2d4bb46fa5b5cdb504ffa4e348a doesn't accept it.

Comment: It works in localhost. Instead of int, I used decimal, Now its works in server SELECT * FROM `books` where `category` = 'Book' ORDER BY CAST(`Accnno` AS DECIMAL) DESC LIMIT 0,10

Comment: Yep, the matter is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql

Comment: INT is not legal datatype for CAST function in MySQL. Use UNSIGNED or SIGNED. Or use implicit convertion `ORDER BY 0 + Accnno` (will fail if first non-space char is not a digit).

Comment: Fix your database design and don't store numbers as strings to begin with. Then you can get rid of the cast completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using implicit conversion:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM books b
WHERE b.category = 'Book'
ORDER BY (Accnno + 0) DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

This will not generate an error.  If `Accnno` does not start with leading zeros and has no decimal places (both of which seem likely), you can also just use string functions:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(accnno) DESC, accnno DESC
```