# How To split and update column at the same time in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, ddl

I'm working on a mini Project for my portfolio. Which is done except there is one column name **size** which *contain integer space and alphabets*. For example

```
size    

3 ABC

4 XYZ

19 pqr
```

I want to update this table by removing the alphabet, So that it looks like this

```
size

3

4

19
```

I have tried different methods, which basically gives me syntax error.

```
alter table bengaluru_house_prices
modify column size substring_index(size, ' ' , 1);



alter table bengaluru_house_prices
modify column size integer;
```

Thank you

Comment: What if you have `3 ABC4` ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Then i would like to retrive only 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Comment: does your column **always** start with a numeric value?

Comment: `UPDATE <table> SET <column> = CAST(<table>.<column> AS UNSIGNED ) WHERE ....`

Comment: Also your SQL is wrong; if you want to update the column definition in MySQL you should be doing: `ALTER TABLE<table> CHANGE <column> <column> INT(10) NOT NULL` . The term "modify" doesn't exist in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like only the starting integers you could use REGEXP_SUBSTR.

Consider the following data.

```
CREATE TABLE bengaluru_house_prices (
 size varchar(20) );

insert into bengaluru_house_prices values ('3 ABC'),('3 ABC 4'),('4 XYZ'),('19 pqr'),('.'),('.'),('19 pqr25');
```

Select,

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(size,"[0-9]+") as new_size 
from bengaluru_house_prices;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> new_size
> 3
> 3
> 4
> 19
> null
> null
> 19
> ```

To update the table, I suggest create another column then update it and drop it in the end

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES bengaluru_house_prices WRITE;
alter table bengaluru_house_prices add column new_size int default null;
update bengaluru_house_prices 
set new_size = REGEXP_SUBSTR(size,"[0-9]+") ;
alter table bengaluru_house_prices drop column size ;
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/2oMqufmi

Comment: Regex is a really expensive way of doing this sort of transition.